# Filtering records city and state

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with name = city and state

```
city

id_city |  name_city         
   1    |   JED
   2    |   RUD
   3    |   DMM
```

state

```
id_state  |  id_for_city | name_state
     1    |      1       | JED1
     2    |      1       | JED2
     3    |      2       | RUH1
     4    |      2       | RUH2
```

I used ComboBox and i have 2

first combobox1 select name_city (it's ok )

second combobox2 i want select name_state through id_for_city but it left join id_city (here it,s not okay )

how i can write query by using left join in java ?

my code :

frst comboBox1 i think it,s ok

```
public void Filecombo() {

    try {

        String sql = "select name_city from  city";

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            options.add(rs.getString("name_city"));

        }
        comboCity.setItems(options);

        pstmt.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

second comboBox2 (here probloem)

```
public void Filecombo2() {

    try {

        String sq2 = " select name_state from state left  join city on city.id_city= state.id_from_city";

        pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sq2);

        rs = pstmt2.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            options2.add(rs.getString("name_state"));

        }

        comboBranch.setItems(options2);
        pstmt.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

> the result If i want to select different cities like RUH or DMM or JED
>   combobox2 will appear Anything related combobox1

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with `java` or `javafx`.  It's simple a `sqlite` query problem.

Comment: I would return the `id_city` and `name_city` in my first query.  I would then use `id_city` from the first query to get the info I need for the second query. I would do something like `select name_state from state where id_state = aCityIdFromTheFirstQuery`.

Comment: @Sedrick but i have many city and state example 
 and id_state just for In order not to repeat any state

Comment: I removed the tag various for the various DBMS. Please tag your DBMS, but please only the one you are really using. I also removed the jQuery tag, that's a JavaScript library and your question shows no signs to be related to that. When you add a tag, a little description pops up. Please read it an check if it is really about what you mean. If it's not, don't add the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not seem to have much to do with Java, and I'll assume that your JDBC code is basically working, and you are already getting a result set, albeit perhaps not exactly what you want.  I think you just need to add a `WHERE` clause to your query:

```
SELECT c.name_state
FROM state s
INNER JOIN city c
    ON c.id_city = s.id_for_city
WHERE
    s.name_city = 'JED';
```

Note that I replaced the left join with an inner join, since you want state names only, which come from the `city` table.  A left join would be desirable if you wanted to return a `NULL` for the case of states which did not match to anything in the other table.  But, that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: If i want to select different cities like RUH or DMM 
combobox2 will appear Anything related to JED only
but i need RUH > RUH1 or RUH2 Example

Comment: This is not your original question, which I have answered.  If you have a SQL question, I would recommend deleting this, and reposting with sample data.